# Where to put a virtualenv directory on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, bash, virtualenv

I am transferring a Python based development system from PC to Mac.  I need to create a virtualenv / directory to store this system.  Where is a good place to put the directory (somewhere easily accessible from a terminal window)?  I am not so savvy on the Mac as the PC, although I could probably write a bash script to change directory and activate the virtualenv.  I am running OS X Mountain Lion (v10.8) and I'm the only user on the system.

Comment: Actually, you can't use a Bash script for this particular task; but a function (or an alias) would be fine.  The reason is that a script will run as the child process of the shell, and children have no way to modify the environment of their parents (apart from if the parent is willing to cooperate, but that's a fairly academic point in this context). (As an aside, functions are more versatile than aliases, so you should probably just forget about aliases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the virtualenvs are only to be used by you, you can take advantage of the ~ (tilde) shortcut which links to your home directory.

```
mkdir ~/venvs
```

**Creating a virtual environment**

You can then create a virtual environment with this command from any dir in the terminal

```
virtualenv ~/venvs/VENV_NAME
```

**Activating a virtual environment**

You can then source a virtual environment with this command

```
source ~/venvs/VENV_NAME/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many as you like and put them where it's convenient.  A common arrangement is to have a dedicated environment for each project; then if each project is in `~/projects/<project>` you could have a virtualenv directory in each project's respective root directory.  So `~/projects/foo/.env` for the virtualenv for project `foo`, `~/projects/bar/.env` for the one for `bar`, etc.  (The use of `.env` is just a convention; again, you can name them any way you like.)